# Use of the word 'nascent'

Tags: word-choice

I'm creating a blog and would like an interesting title. Does "The Nascent Mathematician" make any sense? I've never heard 'nascent' being used to describe anything but businesses and economies.

Comment: Have you looked at the dictionary definition??

Comment: General advice.  For your titles, use only words and phrases that you know.

Comment: budding promising embryonic emerging blossoming burgeoning growing developing flowering fledgling incipient beginning germinal germinating maturing opening potential pullulating sprouting vegetating young bursting forth fresh pubescent shooting up  (see wordhippo.com) Too bad there isn't an M-word in the bunch. I favor alliteration myself. Don

Comment: @HotLicks yes of course I looked at the dictionary definition, but I was unsure if it was appropriate to describe a person

Comment: The [online Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nascent) gives examples of "a nascent middle class", "her nascent singing career", "It was almost 80 years ago that the Wright brothers from Ohio ventured to Kitty Hawk for the uplift its steady winds offered their nascent passion, airplanes", and others.  If you looked at a dictionary you didn't look very hard.

Comment: @HotLicks none of those examples are using 'nascent' to describe an individual, so I still have the grounds to ask this question. Moreover, the accepted answer clearly indicates that the answer is negative. Your acerbic tone is not well-received.

Comment: Thanks for this question that made me discover this word that comes from... French.

Comment: It's the English form of the word "Naissant" which is the gerund of the verb "Naître" (to born, to come up, to spring).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "nascent" is not typically used to describe a single individual. That does not mean you *can't* use the word this way for the name of your website, but it is a nonstandard usage.

Here is the [Wiktionary definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nascent):

> 1. Emerging; just coming into existence.
> 2. (mathematics, obsolete) Describing a quantity of object that is starting to grow from zero or an infinitesimal beginning. Also the creation or identification of an infinitesimal delta.
> 3. Describing the state, aspect, or practice of an abstract concept.
> 4. Of the state of an element at the time it is being generated from some compound or transitioning from one state to another; Newly released from a compound (especially hydrogen and oxygen) by a chemical reaction or electrolysis and possessing heightened reactivity; Newly synthesized (especially protein or RNA) by translation or transcription.

The [Your Dictionary website](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/nascent) provides several examples of the word in various contexts. There is no example of "nascent" being used to describe an individual.

When the word is used in the figurative sense (i.e., definitions #1 and #3 above), the word is typically applied to systems, movements, ideas, institutions, organizations, or emotions.

Comment: So it appears from (2) that if you were appealing specifically to mathematics geeks who would know the term, then it would have a double meaning and potentially be clever.

Comment: @StuW That usage is obsolete, however. I would be surprised if even "mathematics geeks" are familiar with this meaning. Now, if he wanted to name his website "The Nascent Chemist," **that** would be more recognizable and comical.

Comment: @Kyle thanks for the response; btw 'nascent' is not used in mathematics (anymore, at least)